# C# Socket.BeginSend Sometimes Seems to Behave Synchronously?

Tags: c#, sockets

While attempting to send a message for a queue through the BeginSend call seem te behave as a blocking call.

Specificly I have:

```
public void Send(MyMessage message)
{
  lock(SEND_LOCK){
    var state = ...
    try {
      log.Info("Begin Sending...");
      socket.BeginSend(message.AsBytes(),0, message.ByteLength, SocketFlags.None, 
         (r) => EndSend(r), state);
      log.Info("Begin Send Complete.");
    }
    catch (SocketException e) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

The callback would be something like this:

```
  private void EndSend(IAsyncResult result) {
     log.Info("EndSend: Ending send.");
     var state = (MySendState) result.AsyncState;
     ...

     state.Socket.EndSend(result, out code);

     log.Info("EndSend: Send ended.");

     WaitUntilNewMessageInQueue();
     SendNextMessage();
  }
```

Most of the time this works fine, but sometimes it hangs. Logging indicates this happens when BeginSend en EndSend are excecuted on the *same* Thread. The *WaitUntilNewMessageInQueue* blocks until there is a new message in the queue, so when there is no new message it can wait quit a while.

As far as I can tell this should not really be a problem, but in the some cases BeginSend blocks causing a deadlock situation where *EndSend* is blocking on *WaitUntilNewMessageInQueue* (expected), but *Send* is blocking on *BeginSend* in return as it seems te be waiting for the *EndSend* callback te return (not expected).

This behaviour was not what I was expecting. Why does BeginSend sometimes block if the callback does not return in timely fashion?

Comment: Have you tried my suggestions?

Comment: Yes, though I'm not finished yet. Allowing exceptions to tickle down requires some refactoring of the overall design. Removing the locks causes some of my unit tests to fail, but I suspect these are recoverable unhandled exceptions, but need to investigate some more.

Comment: Well my problem is solved, though I'm still unclear as to why I occured in the first place. I consider myself well versed in threading, but clearly my understanding of Sockets is lacking, so I decided to take some time to study the subject. Any refernces would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, why are you locking in your `Send` method? The lock will be released before the send is complete since you are using `BeginSend`. The result is that multiple sends can be executing at the same time.

Secondly, do not write `(r) => EndSend(r)`, just write `EndSend` (without any parameters).

Thrid: You do not need to include the socket in your state. Your `EndSend` method is working like any other instance method. You can therefore access the `socket` field directly.

As for your deadlocks, it's hard to tell. You delegate may have something to do with it (optimizations by the compiler / runner). But I have no knowledge in that area.

Need more help? Post more code. but I suggest that you fix the issues above (all four of them) and try again first.

Comment: I've no idea why this has been down voted, the points made are all valid.

Comment: The lock on the send is not to prevent simultaneous sends, it prevents starting send while the socket is connecting or disconnecting. Adding the socket to the state was to prevent an error where a the socket was replaced by an new instance due to disconnect or changes in configuration.

Comment: Trying to prevent errors by wrapping the send in a lock is the wrong approach. You'll block all calling threads and that can produce a deadlock if you are not careful. Better to throw an exception in the send method or event better: Put the data in a send queue to send it as soon as the socket is connected again.

Comment: Its works now. Removing the lock solved the problem, but it is uncetain if this is because the BeginSend no longer blocks or simply because it is called recussively in the thread.

Comment: A lock will not block the same thread if you call the containing method recursively.

Answer (score 1):

Which operating system are you running on?

Are you sure you're seeing what you think you're seeing?

The notes on the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h44aee9.aspx) say that `Send()` CAN block if there's no OS buffer space to initiate your async send unless you have put the socket in non blocking mode. Could that be the case? Are you potentially sending data very quickly and filling the TCP window to the peer? If you break into the debugger what does the call stack show?

The rest is speculation based on my understanding of the underlying native technologies involved...

The notes for `Send()` are likely wrong about I/O being cancelled if the thread exits, this almost certainly depends on the underlying OS as it's a low level IO Completion Port/overlapped I/O issue that changed with Windows Vista (see here: http://www.lenholgate.com/blog/2008/02/major-vista-overlapped-io-change.html) and given that they're wrong about that then they could be wrong about how the completions (calls to `EndSend()` are dispatched on later operating systems). From Vista onwards it's possible that the completions could be dispatched on the issuing thread if the .Net sockets wrapper is enabling the correct options on the socket (see [here](http://www.lenholgate.com/blog/2010/04/the-design-implications-of-file-skip-completion-port-on-success-and-the-vista-overlapped-io-change.html) where I talk about `FILE_SKIP_COMPLETION_PORT_ON_SUCCESS`)... However, if this were the case then it's likely that you'd see this behaviour a lot as initially most sends are likely to complete 'in line' and so you'd see most completions happening on the same thread - I'm pretty sure that this is NOT the case and that .Net does NOT enable this option without asking...

Comment: After I explicitly set blocking to false the problem appears resolved. I still a little vague on why this is. 'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx' mentions nothing about the blocking mode and my tests were with a single send and receive so spamming was not really an issue.

Comment: I changed the blocking property and it seems to work, but msdn notes "The Blocking property has no effect on asynchronous methods." in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.blocking.aspx so I'm still confused.

Comment: How big was the single send. When you change the blocking mode, does the send that would have blocked actually send the data ? I would assume that if it were to return rather than block then it's the equivalent of it returning E_WOULDBLOCK which basically means you need to retry the operation later... All very strange though.

Comment: It appears I was mistaking. the blocking option altered the establishment of the connection, not the behaviour of the beginsend, but seemd to because sending started before an actual connection was established.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you check if it completed synchronously so you avoid the callback on another thread.

For a single send:

```
var result = socket.BeginSend(...);
if (result.CompletedSynchronously)
{
    socket.EndSend(result);
}
```

For a queue of multiple sends, you can just loop and finalize all synchronous sends:

```
while (true)
{
    var result = socket.BeginSend(...);
    if (!result.CompletedSynchronously)
    {
        break;
    }
    socket.EndSend(result);
}
```